# ImportError: dlopen(...), Symbol not found: _GEOSArea, Referenced From ..., Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: python, homebrew, gdal, rasterio, geos

I'm trying to load in rasterio but for some reason gets this weird error. Anyone knows what this is, what this means and what's the best solution for it?

```
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rasterio._base import gdal_version
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/_base.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _GEOSArea
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/opt/libspatialite/lib/libspatialite.7.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /opt/homebrew/opt/libspatialite/lib/libspatialite.7.dylib
```

I'm running MacOS Big Sur with Python 3.9 if that helps?

Comment: +1 here, getting the same issue on Big Sur, Python 3.8, in my case using SQLAlchemy/SQLite/Spatialite on loading spatialite extension through listener on connect

Comment: do you think this could be an issue with gdal? or with libspatialite. not sure what's the best, whether to install these libraries with brew or with pip.